# Processing a ManagementObjectCollection using Parallel.ForEach(...)

Tags: c#, types, parallel.foreach

I'm using the following code to process all the items in a ManagementObjectCollection in parallel:

```
using (ManagementObjectCollection results = this._searcher.Get())
{
    // The type arguments for method Parallel.ForEach<TSource>(...) cannot be inferred from usage
    Parallel.ForEach(results, (mo, loopState) =>
    {
        // process mo
    });
}
```

If I specify a type, it then complains about this

```
using (ManagementObjectCollection results = this._searcher.Get())
{
    // Cannot convert from ManagementObjectCollection to [..].IEnumereable<ManagementObject>
    Parallel.ForEach<ManagementObject>(results, (mo, loopState) =>
    {
        // process mo
    });
}
```

How can I make this work properly? And why does the second code block not work (AFAICS, ManagementObjectCollection implements IEnumerable so why is it complaining)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface, hence making it an `IEnumerable<object>`, not `IEnumerable<ManagementObject>`.

I'd suggest casting using `Cast<T>` which will cast each element as you iterate:

```
Parallel.ForEach(results.Cast<ManagementObject>(),
                (mo, loopState) =>
{
    // process mo
});
```

If for some reason you need the strongly typed list, you can cast it before:

```
var managementObjects = results.Cast<ManagementObject>().ToList();
Parallel.ForEach(managementObjects, (mo, loopState) =>
{
    // process mo
});
```

Comment: I just read the same thing from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/03/02/9971804.aspx), thanks for your quick answer. Still learning C#!